# What is the meaning of _voci populi_ in this quote?

Tags: translation-check, meaning, word-play

There is one [quote by Victor Klemperer that reads:](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Victor_Klemperer)

> But there is no *vox populi,* only *voci populi.*

which seems to be a bit puzzling.

On a [wiki-talk page the translation speculation runs with the possibility derived from machine translation that both form (*vox/voci*) might be regarded as synonyms?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2017_August_19)

But [analyzing](https://www.latin-is-simple.com/en/analysis/?text=Voci%20populi.%0D%0A) the vocabulary and grammar shows that *voci* is the 3rd person dative singular for 'voice'. And that these [two forms of *vox*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voci) (that entry lists Italian etymologies, but Klemperer wrote mainly in German; so any play of words might use any of the three languages, especially since this should most probably be read as 'written under fascism'?) might shift the 'joke' from 'voice' to sth like 'order'/'command'?

So, this quote is some form of word play? And if it would have to be read as 'strictly Latin throughout' (is it?), then how to translate that?

But what exactly is Klemperer 'voicing' here?

Comment: The third comment under the Wiki explains it, as TKR did below. It's just a mistake in the translation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a mistake in the English translation.

As Adam Bishop in the Wiki discussion you link to says, the quote in German is *Aber es gibt keine vox populi, sondern nur **voces** populi* "But there is no voice of the people, only voices of the people" -- with *voces* as the correct nominative plural form. For some reason, the English translator decided to incorrect Klemperer's Latin.

Comment: +1. There's hardly a language crime worse than foolishly hypercorrecting Latin plurals.

Comment: @cmw "Eh, this Klemperer person is only" (checks notes) "professor of Romance languages, I'll make sure to double check his Latin when translating his book" (checks notes) "Lingua Tertii Imperii."